# Is fragment only useful when the application is designed to run on both phone and tablet?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a forum reader, which I expect that it will be run on phone only, not tablet.

The application originally have 3 views, and each is assigned with an Activity.
For example, if the user select a board on "Board selection screen", an Activity will start, and show the thread list of the selected board to the user.

Recently I have learned how to use fragment in an Android application. therefore I decided to convert my application from an Activity based apps to a Fragment based apps.

Although the apps works as fine as usual after the change, I encountered a problem in saving the state of the fragment. I failed to find the event to let me save the state of fragment (When I am switching from A fragment to B fragment). The most likely event is onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), but according to the API guide, it will only be called when an activity is about to be stopped, and it is not my case.

Actually I have tried to save the state in getArgument() in onDestroyView(). Nevertheless, according to the API guide, the values in getArgument() should only be used for instancing a fragment. Although everything work normal when I am saving the state in getArgument(), I believe that I am doing it wrong.

I have tried to do some googling about Fragment. I found that most of the artist suggest that Fragment is useful when an application is expected to run on both phone and tablet. And I don't find any artist that is talking about how to do screen switching between few Fragment within an Activity. I started to doubt that Fragment are only useful for supporting different device, but not for screen switching.

Sorry for the above junks. My questions are, does Fragment is not very useful when I am developing an application which for phone only? Should I change my application back to an Activity-based apps if I don't expect this to run on tablet?

Comment: "Recently I have learned how to use fragment in an Android application. therefore I decided to convert my application from an Activity based apps to a Fragment based apps." Why? If you know why then why are you asking the question?

Comment: You wouldn't want to be switching back and forth because there's no reason for it. Fragments *are* optional but trying to go Frag after the fact is supposedly hell. + all the points in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing Fragments are good at is they are good for Dialogs. Fragment-based dialogs have none of the problems you usually have with showDialog() when rotating the phone

Answer (score 0):

No, you should stick with Fragments. They're incredibly versatile and will make your life easier down the road if you decide to rearrange things. As far as saving state, you just need to override `onSaveInstanceState()` in your `Fragment` (not the `Activity`). This will absolutely be called when switching between Fragments -- I use this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about "just work" you can just go ahead and use fragments or just normal activities and layouts. However, what fragments provide, apart of scalability when developing for other devices like tablets, is that it's giving you more code separation, which is so, so great for the maintenance of the app.